# remove trailing zeros within the middle of scientific representation

Tags: c++

I need to format a double in a specific way for a checksum.

`0.000045` -> `"4.5e-05"`

`0.0000632` -> `"6.32e-05"`

I tried this:

```
#include <sstream>

std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::scientific << std::showpoint << value;
return ss.str();
```

but I get lots of zeros following the decimal point:

```
"4.500000e-05"
```

Setting the precision does help:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::scientific << std::setprecision(3) << std::showpoint << value;
return ss.str();
```

Output:

```
"4.500e-05"
```

but I can't set the precision because it depends on the input number.

Comment: Hearing "double" and "checksum" in the same sentence, makes me nervous.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for small numbers.

```
std::stringstream ss;
// Resets fixed and set scientific style.
ss.setf(std::ios_base::scientific | std::ios_base::showpoint, std::ios_base::fixed);
ss << value;
return ss.str();  // 4.5e-05 or 6.32e-05
```